# Удаленное подключение к базе Postgresql через Ansible работает не корректно. Postgresql via Ansible does not work correctly

Tags: linux, postgresql, ansible, devops

У меня есть код в playbook:
[image: изменение конфигов postgres]
Запускается на 1 сервере. Всего их 3. На 2-м БД.

Задача проста, сделать так, чтобы доступ к бд через пользователя был только у одного сервера.
Т.е playbook прорабатывает, всё без ошибок, он меняет данные(добавляет строки из скрина), но подключиться я могу как с 1 сервера, так и с 3. А конфиг изменён под 1й сервер. (свой адрес он слушает, а доступ к подключению только у 1 сервера). Но на деле не так. Почему так и как решить?

It runs on 1 server. There are 3 of them in total. On the 2nd DB.

The task is simple, to make sure that only one server has access to the database and the user. Ie, the playbook is working through everything without errors, it changes data, but I can connect from both 1 server and 3. And the config is changed for the 1st server. (he listens to his address, and only 1 server has access to the connection). But in fact it is not so. Why so and how to solve it?

Comment: Т.е. ты 2 таски со скрина хочешь выполнять только на одном серваке, а на других, чтобы они скипались? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @donRumata эти таски выполняются итак на одном сервере, скипая другие сервера, и добавляют строки в файлы (которые не скрине), эти строки должны ограничить удаленное подключение к базе, как я понимаю, но подключение всё равно остается доступным для других серверов( и я не могу понять почему.

Comment: Эммм... поменять внешний ip на 127.0.0.1?